# How to show word onscreen in Pygame through a series of functions

Tags: python, function, pygame

I think there are 2 problems that I have:

1. In `chooseTheme()`, either the return statements or the keys pressed code doesn't work.
2. The `randWord()` function doesn't stop when in the while not done main, it keeps randomizing the word list.

The message in `chooseTheme()` prints.

I've run lines 22-27 separately and it prints out a single word which is what I want.

When trying `randWord("Nations")` instead of `randWord(chooseTheme())` the text shows up but it iterates through the all of the words rather than just picking one.

```
import random
import pygame


pygame.init()

display_width = 1102
display_height = 625

moccasin = (255, 228, 181)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Hangman")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
background = pygame.image.load("world_map.jpg")


def randomWord(theme):
    if theme == "Nations":
        with open("countries_europe.txt") as f:
            word_list = ""
            for word in f:
                word_list = word_list + word
            f.close()
            x = random.choice(word_list.split())
            screen_word = font.render(x, True, BLACK)
            screen.blit(screen_word, [display_width/2, display_height/2])
    elif theme == "Capitals":
        with open("capitals_europe.txt") as f:
            word_list = ""
            for word in f:
                word_list = word_list + word
            f.close()
            x = random.choice(word_list.split())
            screen_word = font.render(x, True, BLACK)
            screen.blit(screen_word, [display_width/2, display_height/2])


def chooseTheme():
    category_text = font.render("Choose a theme:  NATIONS [N] CAPITALS [C]", True, BLACK)
    screen.blit(category_text, (200, display_height/2))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_n:
                return "Nations"
            elif event.key == pygame.K_c:
                return "Capitals"


done = False

while not done:
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    randomWord(chooseTheme())

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

When the keys N or C are pressed, the "Choose theme:" question should disappear and a random word should print onscreen from one of the .txt files.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid calling `pygame.event.get()` multiple times, because each call removes all events from the queue and therefore subsequent calls won't "see" the events that where just removed.

Also, once you press a key, you render the random word in the `randomWord` function, but it would immediatly be overdraw in the next frame. You have to keep track of your game's state (for example, in the code below, think of your game either being in the ChooseTheme-state or in the Word-state).

Here's how you could do it, using sprites (you don't have to, but they are usefull). Note the comments in the code.

```
import random
import pygame
import pygame.freetype

pygame.init()

MOCASSIN = (255, 228, 181)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1102, 625))
pygame.display.set_caption("Hangman")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# let's use freetype instead of font 
# because freetype is just better in every way
FONT = pygame.freetype.SysFont(None, 25)

# let's use a solid Surface instead of a picture
# so we can run the code without the image
# background = pygame.image.load("world_map.jpg")
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_rect().size)
background.fill((30, 30, 30))

# we define a dict of the dicts we want to use
# this allows us to easily add new dicts
# also we seperated data from code
THEMES = {
    'Nations': 'countries_europe.txt',
    'Capitals': 'capitals_europe.txt'
}

# let's cache the words so we don't have to read the files over and over again
cached_themes = {}
def get_theme(theme):
    if not theme in cached_themes:
        with open(THEMES[theme]) as f:
            cached_themes[theme] = [data.strip() for data in f.readlines()]
    return cached_themes[theme]


# we use a Sprite so pygame handles the drawing automatically for us
# this sprite handles the theme choosing
class ChooseTheme(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # we create the message dynamically, so new themes are automatically avaiable
        theme_str = ' '.join(t.upper() + ' [' + t[0].upper() + ']' for t in THEMES)
        self.image =  pygame.Surface(screen.get_rect().size)
        FONT.render_to(self.image, (50, 50), 'Choose a theme: ' + theme_str, MOCASSIN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self, events):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                for theme in THEMES:
                    if theme[0].upper() == event.unicode.upper():
                        # create a new  Word-sprite
                        # self.groups()[0] is the sprites-group created below
                        self.groups()[0].add(Word(theme))
                        # remove this sprite from the game
                        self.kill()

# this sprite handles the displaying of a random word
class Word(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, theme):
        super().__init__()
        self.word = random.choice(get_theme(theme))
        self.image = pygame.Surface(screen.get_rect().size)
        FONT.render_to(self.image, (50, 50), self.word, MOCASSIN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


def main():
    # we use a sprite group to handle updating and drawing
    # since we put all the game logic into the sprites,
    # we probably don't have to touch the main loop again
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(ChooseTheme())
    while True:
        # handle events
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        # update gamestate
        sprites.update(events)

        # draw everything
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help man. When I press the keys N or C the program cuts out and gives me the following traceback error:      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 290: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Basically, I'm making a hangman project the player chooses the category, a random is chosen and then replaced with hyphens on screen. Then the player has to guess letters. If the letter is right then it will replace the hyphen onscreen. How would I go about implementing that?